# How to compare value from the table data and click in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a form where I am passing a value and selenium needs to compare that value with the table data and select it. Since the table data is dynamic not sure how to approach. Please advise

I tried the below:

```
public static void awb_origin_dest(String airport_name){
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){

       List<WebElement> ele=driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
       for(int j=0;j<ele.size();j++) {
           String listOfValues = ele.get(j).getText();
           //System.out.println(listOfValues);
           if (listOfValues.contains(airport_name)) {
               Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
               actions.doubleClick(ele.get(j)).perform();
               break;
           } else {
               continue;
           }
       }
       driver.findElement(By.id("f2ListEnquiry_table_next")).click();
    }
}
```

If I pass value which exists in first few pages I am able to get the required but the loop does not get end and gives the exception as:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with css selector == #f2ListEnquiry_table_next

Please tell if this is right approach or something else should be tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public static void awb_origin_dest(String airport_name){
    boolean found = false; // this will check if airport was found
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){

        List<WebElement> ele=driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for(int j=0;j<ele.size();j++) {
            String listOfValues = ele.get(j).getText();
            //System.out.println(listOfValues);
            if (listOfValues.contains(airport_name)) {
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                actions.doubleClick(ele.get(j)).perform();
                found = true; // catch that airport was found
                break; // break inner loop
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (found){ // if found, break the outer loop
            break; // break outer loop
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("f2ListEnquiry_table_next")).click();
    }
}
```

***Explanation:***

you are breaking only the inner loop if airport was found, but outer loop still loops. That's why I have suggested to introduce a boolean variable to check if airport was found and break outer loop as well, if it is true. Hope it helps.

---

***About:***

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #f2ListEnquiry_table_next
```

- Make sure that you have 50 pages, since you are iterating 50 times in your code.
- try to add `WebDriverWait`. This will wait at least 10 seconds until button will be clickable and only then clicks on it. This will prevent exceptions, if your script will be too quick and will try to click on the button, which not ready to receive click yet.

***Example:***

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("f2ListEnquiry_table_next"))).click();
```

Comment: My table has some 700 pages of record(i.e. 700*10=7000 records) within which I have to look for my value and get since it is taking too long I have intentionally given 50 pages limit. Could you suggest if any way to look for the record in  faster way. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if on your page it is possible, but you could change quantity of entries per page, for example 50 entries per page or even 100.